# Yahoo Finance Api - Missing data for symbols

Tags: yahoo, finance

I'm using Yahoo Finance Api to extract stockrates. To find the symbols using [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/) - but oddly a few of the symbols that Yahoo presents, doesn't return any data when using the API?!

Here are a few examples (Try looking them up with the above url):

- DKIEUIXBNP.CO
- DKIENGKEUO.CO
- DKIGLOIXVAKK.CO

But when trying to extract data. The symbol seems to be unknown.

[API-txt-file-download](http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.txt?s=DKIEUIXBNP.CO,DKIENGKEUO.CO,DKIGLOIXVAKK.CO&f=sl1c1p2bahgvd1)

Using the YQL, it says "Unknown ticker symbol"

[YQL Example](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22DKIGLOIXVAKK.CO%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

Why o' why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the yahoo YQL, but rather their older web-service that returns a CSV. I have an open-source plugin on Grails framework called [yahoofinance](https://github.com/ibaralf/yahoofinance) that gets stock data from yahoo finance. I tested your stock symbols and it does return a response but like I said since these particular stocks have very low trading data, the data returned is mostly 0.0 and N/A

Try using the yahoo web-services (using example symbol)

```
finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=DKIENGKEUO.CO&f=snl1d1t1cc1p2pohgvmlt7a2ba
```

-> f=snl1d1t1cc1p2pohgvmlt7a2ba, represents the statistics you are requesting.